# When I have a selected view and slide down the status bar, when I lift it up again the view is not selected

Tags: android, button, kotlin, fragment, statusbar

So, I have `Fragment` with buttons and when the user clicks on one of them, they get selected and look like this:

[image]

To set the button as selected I first set `onTouchListener` to the `Button` which does that:

```
override fun onTouch(view: View?, event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
  view?.isPressed = true
  if (event?.actionMasked == ACTION_UP) {
        view?.performClick()
  }
  return true
}
```

but when I pull the `StatusBar` down, the `Button` gets deselected and look like this:

[image]

[image]

What I want is the `Button` to stay selected all the time, but `onResume` is not called when I pull up the `StatusBar` so I don't know if that happened or not.

Why does that happen? Is there any callback that is called when the status bar is pulled up or down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that the only callback that is called in this situation is the `onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus: Boolean)` in the `Activity`, but nothing happens in the `Fragment`, so I created an interface:

```
interface ActivityActionsListener {
    fun onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus: Boolean)
}
```

that I implement in the `Fragment` and call from the `Activity` like this:

```
override fun onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus: Boolean) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus)
    (currentFragment as? ActivityActionsListener)?.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus)
}
```

and in the `Fragment`:

```
fun onWindowFocusChanged() {
    setupButtons()
}
```

Comment: but this doesn't trigger twice if onResume is called too?

Answer (score 0):

You Can try Setting Selection again when activity resumes

in The OnResume Method

Hope This Helps

Or Else Post Your Code

Comment: `onResume` is not called when the `StatusBar` hides